# JS syntax to bind 2 objects to the same function calls

Tags: javascript

*update: sorry for the vagueness. I have updated the question

I am using the pusher library, where i create channels and bind it to a function (http://pusherapp.com/docs/quickstart)

```
var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL');

myChannel.bind('thing-create', function(thing) {
   //executes
});
```

In this case, i have 2 objects that subscribe to different channels, but execute the same set of function.

```
var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL');
var myChannel2 = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL2');

//wondering if there is syntax for something like this
(myChannel+myChannel2).bind('thing-create', function(thing) {
   //executes
});
```

I can certainly just repeat it, but I know you can do it in jQuery, so i wonder if there is a way to do this for js objects. Maybe jQuery just iterates the the elements

```
//in jquery, you would do this
$(".xxx",".xxx").bind(...)
```

Comment: What, exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you have two DOM elements which you'd like to bind a DOM event callback function to?

Comment: Are you using any type of library for this binding?

Comment: i have updated the question. these are not dom elements, these are objects. so i am curious about whether this can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var f = function() {...};
a1.bind("xx", f);
a2.bind("xx", f);
```

Comment: `bind()` is not a default property of objects. Without more information, this won't work. I see what you are trying to say but imo the question is too vague to give an answer...

Comment: I agree its a vague question.  However, the example did not show how a1 and a2 are assigned, so I just assumed that object supports a bind method.

Comment: The problem is that unless we know how bind works, we cannot give a specific answer of how to use bind in the manner requested. We must also know if the variables are DOM elements, selector strings, etc.

Comment: the variable are not dom elements, or selectors. these are custom objects with e bind functions. I was wondering if you could bind multiple objects at once, instead of repeating it again and again